# Debugging memory leak problem in parallel code with valgrind

Tags: c++, debugging, memory, valgrind

I am debugging a parallel code. I got error indicating index out of range in some map objects.
The error message says:

```
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'**
**what():  \_Map_base::at**
```

I tried valgrind, and it can not give me exact line where the error happens.
I also tried gdb. No message prints out.

The valgrind message says:

```
==7282== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==7282==    at 0x140A17: PMIU_cmd_output (in /home/system/mpich-install-4.1.1/bin/mpiexec.hydra)
==7282==    by 0x12909D: HYD_pmcd_pmi_send (pmiserv_common.c:49)
==7282==    by 0x1221BF: HYD_pmiserv_pmi_reply (pmiserv_pmi.c:28)
==7282==    by 0x11EE55: HYD_pmiserv_barrier (pmiserv_misc.c:32)
==7282==    by 0x11F9A8: handle_pmi_cmd (pmiserv_cb.c:95)
==7282==    by 0x121702: control_cb (pmiserv_cb.c:337)
==7282==    by 0x137818: HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (demux_poll.c:75)
==7282==    by 0x12362B: HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (pmiserv_pmci.c:178)
==7282==    by 0x11099A: main (mpiexec.c:246)
==7282==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==7282==    at 0x11EDA4: HYD_pmiserv_barrier (pmiserv_misc.c:15)
```

I am wondering if there is any tool that can help me deal with such problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I silly question, did you compile with "debug symbols"? It's the `-g` flag for GCC

Comment: No memory leak here. You are accessing outside a vectors limits.  Running it under geb should halt at the offending line. The valgrind error is picking something's ng else up.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Yes, I do compile with -g flag for gcc. I tried running under gdb with mpirun, but it stuck after some new thread messages. This error only occurs when I tried to run it parallel. I am looking at thousands of lines of code, so I cannot post it here.

Comment: Unless otherwise specified datastructures will NOT be threadsafe. At least you should have some kind of mutex. Ideally a reader/writer lock : https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/reader-writer-locks

Comment: "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" does that say "leak"? I can't see the word "leak" there. So I think it's quite safe to assume that this is not a leak.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the code here

```
==7282==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==7282==    at 0x11EDA4: HYD_pmiserv_barrier (pmiserv_misc.c:15)
```

and then figure out what needs to be done to initialize whatever it is.